Future inextendible curve
The definition of future inextendible curve is as follows:
A causal curve $\gamma$ is called future inextendible if it is impossible to find an event p $\in \mathcal{M}$ such that for all $U \subset \mathcal{M}$, $U$ neighborhood of p, there exists a $t'$ such that $\gamma(t) \in U$ for all $t>t'$
I understand the first half of definition but having trouble to understand "there exists a $t'$ such that $\gamma(t) \in U$ for all $t>t'$"
Is $t$ a parameter here? when it says $t'$, does it mean we can't draw another curve $\gamma(t')$
Is it possible to visualize such curves? How do we draw the diagram for this?

your question has nothing to do with differential geometry or general relativity or causality. It’s a very basic matter of understanding quantified statements in mathematics. If I say something like “a function $f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ is eventually bounded by $100$ if there is an $R>0$ such that for all $x>R$ we have $|f(x)|\leq 100$”, are you still confused by its meaning?

It is not that notion, it is the definition of limit. Here there is a quantifier with respect to your description: for any given $U$ there is a corresponding $t’$ such that…The case you consider refers to only one $U$.

The causal future directed curve $\gamma=\gamma(t)$ is defined in an open interval $t\in (a,b)$ with $-\infty \leq a<b \leq +\infty$.  An equivalent way to state the considered definition is that $\gamma$ is future inextendible if there is no point $p$ in the spacetime such that $\gamma(t)\to p$ for $t\to b^-$.

so for past inextendible, we say $\gamma \rightarrow p$ for $t \rightarrow b^{-}$ or $a^{-}$ ???

In that case the right limit is $t\to a^+$…
